# D3 axis: set domain based on numbers but display them as strings

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have for dataset an array of objects like so

```
[
 {
  time: '20:07',
  seconds: 7620,
  value: 49,995
 },
 ...
]
```

I'm currently creating X axis like so

```
this.x = d3.scaleLinear()          
      .domain(this.values.map(function(d) { return d.seconds}))
      .range([ 0, width])
              
this.chart.append('g')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(this.x))
```

what happens now is following
[image: current x axis]

so this correct domain, 7620 is smallest seconds value and 7800 highest, but now instead of showing seconds I wish to display 'time' value. First label on x axis would be then '20:07' instead of 7620.

In a nutshell, create domain based on seconds but show time instead. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform the tick labels using `tickFormat`:

```js
this.chart.append('g')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(this.x).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%H:%M")))
```

Comment: if I just added tickFormat like you wrote, it did not change anything. I still see seconds on axis.

Comment: @Jeekim Could you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: I think the thing is that domain uses just numbers as seconds, not Javascript Date format. I believe I can make it as Date so then timeformat should work I believe

Comment: `tickFormat` accepts a callback. You're not limited to d3 methods in how you transform your data to generate ticks.

Comment: Ill mark this as accepted answer. I did manage to make it work by adding .tickFormat but I had to first create an array of labels (strings containing time). This array has same amount of elements as there will be ticks and then it works like so

this.chart.append('g')
        .call(
          d3
            .axisBottom(this.x)
            .tickFormat((d, i) => { return this.tickLabels[i] })
        )

Answer (score 0):

```
this.x = d3.scaleBand()          
      .domain(array.map(value=>value.time))
      .range([ 0, width])
```

for custom labels i prefer to use **scaleBand()**